# Selecting a integer variable as string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have three columns:

```
id, username, password
```

As you know, `id` values are integers. So how can I select `id` as a string value?

Note that: This is a query that I want to perform on a MSDB server. I couldn't tag because of low reputation points.

Comment: Can you explain this part `select id as a string value`

Comment: read about `Convert`

Comment: Please use :  SELECT CAST(id as varchar(5) ).

Answer (score 1):

Computers can only understand numbers, so an ASCII code is the numerical representation of a character

([asciitable.com](http://asciitable.com))

The ascii function

> Returns the ASCII code value of the leftmost character of a character expression.

[SQL Server 2014 - String Functions - ASCII (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177545.aspx)

it returns `INT` and can be convert to `TINYINT`

```
 SELECT convert(tinyint,ascii('u'))
```

Comment: You could write a few words about it for those who stumble upon you answer ;-)

Comment: Computers can only understand numbers, so an ASCII code is the numerical representation of a character (http://www.asciitable.com)                        The ascii function returns the ASCII code value of the leftmost character of a character expression  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177545.aspx).it returns INT and can be convert to TINYINT.

Comment: If you edit your answer and add the description from the comment to it then I might consider to give you a +1 ;-]

Comment: It is worth more then one +1   -:))

Comment: Haha! Unfortunatelly I can give only one upvote... however now when the answer is improved your changes to get more are increased ;-)

Comment: So can you tell me why the hell this query, `select name from sys.syscolumns where xtype in (select convert(tinyint, ascii('U')))`, isn't working?

Comment: convert('please','hell') !

Comment: ....and i think what you need is 'select name from sys.objects where type in ('U')'   http://sequelserver.blogspot.co.il/2008/08/xtype-onm-syscolumns.html

Answer (score 0):

Try [Cast or Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) (assuming T-SQL)j. [Here's](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a16434f3-5b94-44a1-a8cf-d66f832e1195/convert-integer-to-string) another helpful link.

```
SELECT CAST(id as varchar) FROM ...
```

Comment: What if I want to CAST 'U' value to tinyint? It's a string not a column name.

Comment: Have you attempted to google this at all? First result: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/can-i-convert-string-integer

Comment: @emreaydin149 - I think you are confuse that what you want OR you are confusing us.